# How does the JMP return to the caller in this program?

Tags: assembly, x86

Portion of a for loop

```
    ; .......

    jmp SHORT $LN3@clearArray                ; enter the loop body

$LN2@clearArray:                                 ; incrementation
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _p$2534[ebp]          
    add eax, 4
    mov DWORD PTR _p$2534[ebp], eax

$LN3@clearArray:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _p$2534[ebp]          ; check conditions
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR _length$[ebp]
    jae SHORT $LN4@clearArray                ; when loop condition fails...

; 6    :    {
; 7    :        *p = 0;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _p$2534[ebp]          ; loop body
    mov DWORD PTR [eax], 0

; 8    :    }

    jmp SHORT $LN2@clearArray

$LN4@clearArray:

; ........
```

When $LN2 is completed, how does it return back to $LN3?
This is generated by Visual Studio 2010 C++ assembler output.

Thank you.

Comment: if you downvoted this thread, it is better to state your reason rather than just downvote and leave. I hate downvote without giving the reason. It may seem trivial to some, but sometime people happen to forget stuff. This is why stackoverflow exists. Sometime I see very good engineers posting questions here and I can answer them by just looking at the error and they couldn't. That's because I am an outsider and I look at the problem clearly. So please don't downvote without a reason. It is plain ignorant. How to improve my question quality? By giving me feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `jmp` instruction acts like a `goto` statement.  It transfers control to a new location and execution continues at that point; you don't return from a `jmp` (though you could issue another `jmp`).

In this particular example, the code at $LN2 falls through to $LN3, so every time $LN2 executes, $LN3 will execute.  The code at $LN3 is comparing the loop counter to see if it has reached the maximum value.  The `cmp` ("compare") and `jae` ("jump above or equal") instructions perform the comparison, and then exit the loop if the condition has been met (i.e., counter is equal to or greater than length).  In other words, if your loop counter < length, then `jae` does nothing and falls through to the next instruction.  However, if counter >= length, then you jump to $LN4 which exits the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Errrr... What do you mean, how? The control flow just continues from the `mov DWORD PTR...` instruction to the next one, which is `mov eax, DWORD PTR`.

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thank you. I think cbranch got it. I was mainly interested in the jmp instruction. I probably confused myself. Thanks.